# Get the key with the minimum value in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have to write a function `find_first_read` in order to find the particular Read-key in the dictionary of dictionaries, that contain values less than 2

**desired output**

```
find_first_read(some_dict)
'Read4'
```

What should I change in my code below to get the desired output:

```
some_dict = {'Read1': {'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read5': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 29},
            'Read3': {'Read1': 0, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1, 'Read6': 1},
            'Read2': {'Read1': 13, 'Read3': 1, 'Read5': 21, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 0},
            'Read5': {'Read1': 39, 'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 14},
            'Read4': {'Read1': 1, 'Read3': 1, 'Read2': 17, 'Read5': 2, 'Read6': 0},
            'Read6': {'Read1': 0, 'Read3': 43, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1}}


def find_first_read(some_dict):
    positions = [] # output variable
    min_value = 2
    for k, v in some_dict.items():
        if v < min_value:
            positions.append(k)
    return positions
```

Comment: Why the desired output is `Read4`? There are values less than 2 all over the place.

Comment: Is because `Read4` has all values less than 2?

Comment: Yes, correct. Read4 has all values less than 2

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to compare your min_value to another dict. You have to add another loop to get the nested values. To make the output more clear, I return it as a list of keys instead of a single key to make up for the nesting.

```python
some_dict = {'Read1': {'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read5': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 29},
            'Read3': {'Read1': 0, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1, 'Read6': 1},
            'Read2': {'Read1': 13, 'Read3': 1, 'Read5': 21, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 0},
            'Read5': {'Read1': 39, 'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 14},
            'Read4': {'Read1': 1, 'Read3': 1, 'Read2': 17, 'Read5': 2, 'Read6': 0},
            'Read6': {'Read1': 0, 'Read3': 43, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1}}


def find_first_read(some_dict):
    positions = [] # output variable
    min_value = 2
    for k, v in some_dict.items():
        for ki, vi in v.items():
            if vi < min_value:
                positions.append([k, ki])
    return positions
    

print(find_first_read(some_dict))
```

output:

```
[['Read1', 'Read3'], ['Read1', 'Read2'], ['Read1', 'Read5'], ['Read1', 'Read4'], 
['Read3', 'Read1'], ['Read3', 'Read2'], ['Read3', 'Read5'], ['Read3', 'Read4'], 
['Read3', 'Read6'], ['Read2', 'Read3'], ['Read2', 'Read4'], ['Read2', 'Read6'], 
['Read5', 'Read3'], ['Read5', 'Read2'], ['Read5', 'Read4'], ['Read4', 'Read1'], 
['Read4', 'Read3'], ['Read4', 'Read6'], ['Read6', 'Read1'], ['Read6', 'Read2'], 
['Read6', 'Read5'], ['Read6', 'Read4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_first_read(data):

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key, values in data.items():
        for k, v in values.items():
            d[k].append(v)

    # for example the dictionary has the item "Read4", [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    return next(k for k, vs in d.items() if all(v < 2 for v in vs))


some_dict = {'Read1': {'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read5': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 29},
             'Read3': {'Read1': 0, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1, 'Read6': 1},
             'Read2': {'Read1': 13, 'Read3': 1, 'Read5': 21, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 0},
             'Read5': {'Read1': 39, 'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 14},
             'Read4': {'Read1': 1, 'Read3': 1, 'Read2': 17, 'Read5': 2, 'Read6': 0},
             'Read6': {'Read1': 0, 'Read3': 43, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1}}

res = find_first_read(some_dict)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Read4
```

**Steps**

After the nested for loops, `d` has the following value:

```
{'Read1': [0, 13, 39, 1, 0],
 'Read2': [1, 0, 1, 17, 0],
 'Read3': [0, 1, 0, 1, 43],
 'Read4': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 'Read5': [1, 0, 21, 2, 0],
 'Read6': [29, 1, 0, 14, 0]}
```

The final line uses [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to fetch the first value of the generator expression:

```
k for k, vs in d.items() if all(v < 2 for v in vs)
```

this expression iterates over the key, value pairs of `d` and returns the keys that has all values less than `2`, the last part is checked using the function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
positions=[]
for k, v in some_dict.items():
  for x, y in v.items():
    if y>=2:
      positions.append(x)
positions = list(set(positions))
output=[]
for k in some_dict:
  if k not in positions:
    output.append(k)
print(output)
```

output:

```
['Read4']
```